# PHP static variable persisting in multiple calls

Tags: php, php-7.1

I'm trying to write a class with static chainable methods, but the weirdest thing is happening with my variables persisting between calls.

```
<?php

class foo {
    private static $a = '#';

    public static function more($string)
    {
        self::$a .= $string;
        return new static;
    }

    public static function print()
    {
        echo self::$a . "\n";
    }
}

foo::print();
foo::more('foo')->more('foo')->print();
foo::more('foo')->print();
```

Output:

```
#
#foofoo
#foofoofoo
```

The first and second lines look right to me.  But why on earth would the third line have 3 foos?  The $a variable in the foo class is somehow persisting between calls.  I thought static calls created their own temporary object that has nothing to do with previous calls.

Anybody got an explanation or workaround?

Comment: because you're calling `more`. It's the same reason the second line is `#foofoo`. static is at the class level, not object level.

Comment: "PHP variables persist for the lifetime of the script running through the interpreter." Guess that explains it quite good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, static variables are persistent between calls.

A static property is linked to a class, not an object.

Else, where would it be stored between your calls ?